# Swapping circular linked list nodes around

Tags: java

basically I have to move a set of nodes in a circular linked list to a different spot in the same linked list.

```
      prev  ptr
```

[1]-->[2]-->[3]-->[4]
<--------------------
Let's say I wanted to move 1 and 2 between 3 and 4, and have 4 circle back to 3.
I have temp pointers that point to 1 (temp1), 3 (temp3), and 4 (temp4).
I assume these are the important pointers to manipulate so I set temps for them.

How can I set the prev and ptr pointers to coordinate with the temp pointers?
This is very confusing, any combination I put together and try to print the list,
it will put me into an infinite loop. I want to understand a precise method in approaching
this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to think of the operation as two distinct operations.  A removal, and then an insertion.

```
// remove the node
Node node = ...; // whatever identifies the node to operate on
prev(node).setNext(next(node));

// insert it into its new position
Node newPrev = ...; // whatever identifies the node to operate on
Node newNext = newPrev.next();
newPrev.setNext(node);
node.setNext(newNext);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to suggest.  And then, of course, these operations should be wrapped in their own functions that look something like `llRemove(LIST *list, NODE *node)` and 'llAdd(LIST *list, NODE *node, NODE *after)`

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the approach of enonu doesn't work in some special cases like if one of the nodes is right next to the other or if both refer to the same node.

The following approach swaps two nodes A and B by observing the P<sub>A</sub>, predecessor of A and S<sub>B</sub>, the successor of B. First, we remove A and B, then we insert A left of S<sub>B</sub> and finally B right of P<sub>A</sub>. In the special case that A is the successor of B, we restart with swapped parameters. If both are the successors of one-another, we do nothing.

```
private void swap(Node a, Node b) {
    if (a.pred == b) {
        if (b.pred != a)
            swap(b, a);

         return;
    }

    Node pa = a.pred, sb = b.succ;

    // remove a from list
    pa.succ = a.succ;
    pa.succ.pred = pa;

    // remove b from list
    sb.pred = b.pred;
    sb.pred.succ = sb;

    // add a before sb
    a.pred = sb.pred;
    a.succ = sb;
    a.pred.succ = a;
    a.succ.pred = a;

    // add b after pa
    b.succ = pa.succ;
    b.pred = pa;
    b.pred.succ = b;
    b.succ.pred = b;
}
```